# no battery present

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I'm using a MacBook 13" (early 2007) running 10.4.11 and it was recently given to me so I have no idea what it's been thru. The battery indicater is showing the X & the system profiler is stating no battery available. My question is after doing a SMC reset with no change is this definetly a battery connector or motherboard issue or is there any chance a new battery may be a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Applications->Utilities there is an app called SystemInformation. Start it, on the left side select "Power", on the right side find (battery..) "health information" cycle count should not be more than 500 and condition should be "normal". Anything other than "normal" means: *replace the battery*. Do that asap as the battery may be leaking or swelling. You may take it out and run on the charger only, but the cpu will be heating a bit more then.
Do not buy a cheap third party battery because they are s**t and will die very fast.

Comment: no app call systeminfo in utilities